# FileHelpers Question - How to Read Fixed Length File without Line Breaks or Delimiters

Tags: filehelpers

How can you use FileHelpers to read Fixed length file with no line breaks or delimiters? Basically, one to many records on a single line. I have to read in a fixed length record with 13 fields totaling 80 characters. If there are 3 records, for example, that would be a single line with 240 characters in it. The answer can't be go to the source and have them output the file differently. They won't budge. I can abandon FileHelpers, but I like how it works and I first want to see if it's possible before I move on. To answer this, you would have to be firmiliar with FileHelpers.

Here is a simple sample like I explained above with 34 records...

```
var FileContent = "car  2010Ford      Mustang        Truck2011Chevy     S10            Car  2018Toyota    Corola         SUV  2017Jeep      Wrangler       ";

[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
public class dtoCarRecord
{
    [FieldFixedLength(5)]
    public string Type;

    [FieldFixedLength(4)]
    public string Year;

    [FieldFixedLength(10)]
    public string Make;

    [FieldFixedLength(15)]
    public string Model;
}

void ApplyDateUpdates(object parameter)
    {
        var raRecords = new List<dtoRARecord>();

        var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<dtoRARecord>();

        // Read
        using (engine.BeginReadFile((string)parameter))
        {
            // The engine is IEnumerable
            foreach (dtoRARecord detail in engine)
            {
                // your code here
                raRecords.Add(detail);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting 4 records out of this file.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with your current code. Also refer to [ask].

Comment: Sure... I'll make up a whole new scenario because what I have can't be shared. Give me a few.

Answer (score 0):

Just split your file every 80 characters before importing it.

```
private static string SplitIntoChunks(string text, int maxWidth)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(text);

    for (int i = 1; i < (sb.Length / maxWidth); i++)
    {
        int insertPosition = i * maxWidth + i - 1;
        sb.Insert(insertPosition, "\n");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

var splitIntoChunks = SplitIntoChunks(FileContent, 34);

using (engine.BeginReadString(splitIntoChunks))
{
    // The engine is IEnumerable
    foreach (dtoRARecord detail in engine)
    {
        // your code here
        raRecords.Add(detail);
    }
}
Assert.AreEqual(4, raRecords.Count());
```

Comment: Sure, I can do that. I was hoping I could do it all with the read from the file, but that's not that big of a trade off. Thank you.